# Are drawing tablets supported in Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, graphics-tablet

I was wondering if digital drawing boards (Handwriting Tablets, Pen Tablets, Drawing Tablets, Graphics Tablets) are supported in Ubuntu for presentations, pointing devices and normal drawing. For example:

[image]

[image]

The reason I ask is for some video tutorials I am making and it would make my life a little easier to explain some stuff while drawing it.

Comment: can you post details of which specific drawing tablet you have?  Many are supported.

Comment: Wacom Bamboo series for example, The Vistablets or DigiPro. Any tablet that includes a pen to digitally write with. At the moment I have those in mind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm certain Wacom tablets are natively supported. In fact, I have a control panel for them on my stock 12.04 Desktop install.

Answer (score 3):

I have a wacom tablet.

It works as a mouse, perfectly.

Also, gimp (and other drawing programs) have support for it